# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

Estou com esse erro aqui:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:19)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
at Main.Interface.<init>(Interface.java:17)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas$AçãoDosBotoes.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:82)
at Main.AçaoDasTeclas.<init>(AçaoDasTeclas.java:24)
```

Classe 1:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Interface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

char operacao;
double num1, num2, resultado;
String numant, temp, copiar;

AçaoDasTeclas adt = new AçaoDasTeclas();

public Interface() {
    initComponents();
    adt.AçõesDoTeclado(Painel);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    Painel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Op = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    Display = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    BT0 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BT9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTSomar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTDiminuir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTMultiplicar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTDividir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTLimpar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTce = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTPonto = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTraiz = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTtrocar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BTIgual = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Calculadora");
    setResizable(false);
    addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            formKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    Op.setEditable(false);
    Op.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    Op.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);

    Display.setEditable(false);
    Display.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    Display.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
    Display.setFocusable(false);

    BT0.setText("0");
    BT0.setFocusable(false);
    BT0.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    BT0.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    BT0.addActionListener(adt.ActBT0);

    BT1.setText("1");
    BT1.addActionListener(adt.ActBT1);

    BT2.setText("2");
    BT2.addActionListener(adt.ActBT2);

    BT3.setText("3");
    BT3.addActionListener(adt.ActBT3);

    BT4.setText("4");
    BT4.addActionListener(adt.ActBT4);

    BT5.setText("5");
    BT5.addActionListener(adt.ActBT5);

    BT6.setText("6");
    BT6.addActionListener(adt.ActBT6);

    BT7.setText("7");
    BT7.addActionListener(adt.ActBT7);

    BT8.setText("8");
    BT8.addActionListener(adt.ActBT8);

    BT9.setText("9");
    BT9.addActionListener(adt.ActBT9);

    BTSomar.setText("+");
    BTSomar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTSomarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTDiminuir.setText("-");
    BTDiminuir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTDiminuirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTMultiplicar.setText("*");
    BTMultiplicar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTMultiplicarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTDividir.setText("/");
    BTDividir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTDividirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTLimpar.setText("C");
    BTLimpar.setToolTipText("Limpar visor.");
    BTLimpar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTLimparActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTce.setText("CE");
    BTce.setToolTipText("Apagar a ultima operação feita.");
    BTce.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTceActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTPonto.setText(".");
    BTPonto.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTPontoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTraiz.setText("√¯");
    BTraiz.setToolTipText("Raiz quadrada.");
    BTraiz.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTraizActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTtrocar.setText("-\\+");
    BTtrocar.setToolTipText("Trocar o sinal do número.");
    BTtrocar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTtrocarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BTIgual.setText("=");
    BTIgual.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            BTIgualActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jMenu2.setMnemonic('e');
    jMenu2.setText("Editar");

    jMenuItem1.setMnemonic('c');
    jMenuItem1.setText("Copiar");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setMnemonic('v');
    jMenuItem2.setText("Colar");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    jMenu1.setText("Sobre");
    jMenu1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jMenu1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(Painel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(Painel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void SOp(String op) {
    Op.setText(Display.getText() + " " + op);
}

private void ResultOp(char op) throws NumberFormatException {
    operacao = op;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());
    Display.setText(null);
}

private void BTPontoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if("".equals(Display.getText())) {
        Display.setText("0.");
    } else {
        Display.setText(Display.getText() + ".");
    }
}                                       

private void BTSomarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    SOp("+");
    ResultOp('+');
}                                       

private void BTIgualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    Op.setText(null);
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());

    if(operacao == '+'){
        resultado = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if(operacao == '-'){
        resultado = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if(operacao == '*'){
        resultado = num1 * num2;
    }
    else{
        resultado = num1 / num2;
    }

    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(resultado);

    Display.setText(Double.toString(resultado));
}                                       

private void BTDiminuirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    SOp("-");
    ResultOp('-');
}                                          

private void BTMultiplicarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    SOp("*");
    ResultOp('*');
}                                             

private void BTDividirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    SOp("/");
    ResultOp('/');
}                                         

private void BTceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    num2 = 0;
    Display.setText(String.valueOf(num1));
}                                    

private void BTLimparActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
    Display.setText(null);
    Op.setText(null);
}                                        

private void BTraizActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    temp = Display.getText();
    Op.setText("√¯" + "("+ temp +")" );
    temp = String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(Display.getText())));
    Display.setText(temp);
}                                      

private void BTtrocarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    temp = String.valueOf(-1 * Double.parseDouble(Display.getText()));
    Display.setText(temp);
}                                        

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    copiar = Display.getText();

    Clipboard board = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();   
           ClipboardOwner Selecao = new StringSelection(temp);   
           board.setContents((Transferable) Selecao, Selecao);
}                                          

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    temp = copiar;
    Display.setText(temp);
}                                          

private void jMenu1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    new Sobre(this, true).setVisible(true);
}                                   

private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ADD) {
        SOp("+");
        ResultOp('+');
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT) {
        SOp("-");
        ResultOp('-');
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY) {
        SOp("*");
        ResultOp('*');
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE) {
        SOp("/");
        ResultOp('/');
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        Op.setText(null);
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(Display.getText());

    if(operacao == '+'){
        resultado = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if(operacao == '-'){
        resultado = num1 - num2;
    }
    else if(operacao == '*'){
        resultado = num1 * num2;
    }
    else {
        resultado = num1 / num2;
    }

    Display.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD) {
        Display.setText(Display.getText() + ".");
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        Display.setText("");
        BTPonto.setEnabled(true);
    } else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
        if(Display.getText().length() > 0) {
            String substring = Display.getText().substring(0, Display.getText().length() - 1);
            Display.setText(substring);
        }
    }
    if(Display.getText().contains(".")) {
        BTPonto.setEnabled(false);
    }
}                               

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Interface().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public static javax.swing.JButton BT0;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT1;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT2;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT3;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT4;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT5;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT6;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT7;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT8;
public static javax.swing.JButton BT9;
private javax.swing.JButton BTDiminuir;
private javax.swing.JButton BTDividir;
private javax.swing.JButton BTIgual;
private javax.swing.JButton BTLimpar;
private javax.swing.JButton BTMultiplicar;
private javax.swing.JButton BTPonto;
private javax.swing.JButton BTSomar;
private javax.swing.JButton BTce;
private javax.swing.JButton BTraiz;
private javax.swing.JButton BTtrocar;
public javax.swing.JTextField Display;
private javax.swing.JTextField Op;
private javax.swing.JPanel Painel;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
```

Classe 2:

```
public class AçaoDasTeclas {

private final JButton BT0 = Interface.BT0;
private final JButton BT1 = Interface.BT1;
private final JButton BT2 = Interface.BT2;
private final JButton BT3 = Interface.BT3;
private final JButton BT4 = Interface.BT4;
private final JButton BT5 = Interface.BT5;
private final JButton BT6 = Interface.BT6;
private final JButton BT7 = Interface.BT7;
private final JButton BT8 = Interface.BT8;
private final JButton BT9 = Interface.BT9;

public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT0 = new AçãoDosBotoes(0);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT1 = new AçãoDosBotoes(1);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT2 = new AçãoDosBotoes(2);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT3 = new AçãoDosBotoes(3);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT4 = new AçãoDosBotoes(4);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT5 = new AçãoDosBotoes(5);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT6 = new AçãoDosBotoes(6);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT7 = new AçãoDosBotoes(7);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT8 = new AçãoDosBotoes(8);
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT9 = new AçãoDosBotoes(9);

public void AçõesDoTeclado(javax.swing.JPanel painel) {
    ActionMap ActMap = painel.getActionMap();
    ActMap.put(BT0, ActBT0);
    ActMap.put(BT1, ActBT1);
    ActMap.put(BT2, ActBT2);
    ActMap.put(BT3, ActBT3);
    ActMap.put(BT4, ActBT4);
    ActMap.put(BT5, ActBT5);
    ActMap.put(BT6, ActBT6);
    ActMap.put(BT7, ActBT7);
    ActMap.put(BT8, ActBT8);
    ActMap.put(BT9, ActBT9);
    painel.setActionMap(ActMap);

    InputMap imap = painel.getInputMap(javax.swing.JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("0"), BT0);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("1"), BT1);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("2"), BT2);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("3"), BT3);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("4"), BT4);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("5"), BT5);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("6"), BT6);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("7"), BT7);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("8"), BT8);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("9"), BT9);

    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD0"), BT0);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD1"), BT1);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD2"), BT2);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD3"), BT3);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD4"), BT4);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD5"), BT5);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD6"), BT6);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD7"), BT7);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD8"), BT8);
    imap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD9"), BT9);
}

public class AçãoDosBotoes extends AbstractAction {

    private final int numero;

    private final JTextField Display;

    public AçãoDosBotoes(int numero) {
        super(Integer.toString(numero));
        this.Display = new Interface().Display;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Display.setText(Display.getText() + numero);
    }
}
}
```

Como resolve??

Comment: O problema é causado por um loop infinito no construtor de um JFrame. Poderia postar o código da sua classe?

Comment: Postei só o construtor do JFrame... Tá bom?

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não dá pra identificar o loop. Tem como colocar a exceção inteira e a classe inteira?

Comment: A exceção não deu pra colocar tudo mas me parece ser uma coisa repetitiva...

Comment: Em `AçaoDasTeclas` você instancia varias vezes `AçãoDosBotoes`, em `AçãoDosBotoes` você instancia `Interface`, em `Interface` você instancia `AçaoDasTeclas` e assim para todo o sempre =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme dito nos comentários há um ciclo na construção dos seus objetos, o que irá gerar o [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

No seu caso há o seguinte ciclo:

1. `Interface` intancia `AçaoDasTeclas` (`AçaoDasTeclas adt = new AçaoDasTeclas();`);
2. `AçaoDasTeclas` instancia `AçãoDosBotoes` várias vezes (ex: `public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT0 = new AçãoDosBotoes(0);`)
3. `AçãoDosBotoes` instancia `Interface` (`this.Display = new Interface().Display;`)
4. volte em `1` =)

Então, para corrigir isto você terá que corrigir a forma com que está passando as mensagens, etc. Um exemplo seria seguir os seguintes passos:

- alterar o construtor de `AçãoDosBotoes` para receber o `JTextField` `display`, algo assim:

```java
public AçãoDosBotoes(final int numero, JTextField Display) {
    super(Integer.toString(numero));
    this.Display = Display;
    this.numero = numero;
}
```

- criar um construtor para `AçaoDasTeclas` para receber o `JTextField` `display` e assim poder passar para os `AçãoDosBotoes`, algo desta forma:

```java
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT0;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT1;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT2;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT3;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT4;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT5;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT6;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT7;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT8;
public AçãoDosBotoes ActBT9;

public AçaoDasTeclas(final JTextField display) {
    this.ActBT0 = new AçãoDosBotoes(0, display);
    this.ActBT1 = new AçãoDosBotoes(1, display);
    this.ActBT2 = new AçãoDosBotoes(2, display);
    this.ActBT3 = new AçãoDosBotoes(3, display);
    this.ActBT4 = new AçãoDosBotoes(4, display);
    this.ActBT5 = new AçãoDosBotoes(5, display);
    this.ActBT6 = new AçãoDosBotoes(6, display);
    this.ActBT7 = new AçãoDosBotoes(7, display);
    this.ActBT8 = new AçãoDosBotoes(8, display);
    this.ActBT9 = new AçãoDosBotoes(9, display);
}
```

- em `Interface` altere a construção de `AçaoDasTeclas` para receber `display` e leve `display` para antes deles, deverá se parecer com isto:

```java
public javax.swing.JTextField Display;
AçaoDasTeclas adt = new AçaoDasTeclas(this.Display);
```

Obs. 1: isto é um exemplo que "roda", sugiro revisar seu código de forma a organizá-lo de forma mais coesa e desacoplada

Obs. 2: evite usar caracteres especiais em nomes de classes, métodos, variáveis, etc. Então, considere alterar de `AçaoDasTeclas` para `AcaoDasTeclas` e assim por diante.